# Javascript Array Dynimic

Tags: javascript

i have a javascript code like below

```
function createArray()
{
    var myArr = new Object();
    myArr[0] = createSubArray('apple');
    myArr[1] = createSubArray('Mango');
    myArr[2] = createSubArray('Pineapple');
    myArr[3] = createSubArray('Grape'); */
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return myArr;
} 

function createSubArray(name){
    var arr = new Object();
    elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        if (elems[i].checked){
            arr[name] =  elems[i].value;
            arr['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    }
    return arr;

}
```

I need to change this createArray() function into dynimic but i dont know how this is possible
here is my code that i have tried

```
function createArray()
{
    var myArr = new Object();
    elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
     for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        var elmcheck = elems[i].getAttribute('type');
        //alert(elmcheck);
        if (elems[i].checked)
        {
         alert("A Radio Is Check "+elems[i].getAttribute('name'));
         myArr[i] = createSubArray(elems[i].getAttribute('name'));
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return myArr;
} 

function createSubArray(name){
    var arr = new Object();
    elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
        if (elems[i].checked){
            arr[name] =  elems[i].value;
            arr['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    }
    return arr;

}
```

but its not working can any one help me in solving..

Comment: Install Firebug and you can replace "alert" with "console.debug" etc

Comment: ...also, Firebug (and the built-in developer tools) will let you try out javascript expressions in the js console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this it may work for you

```
function createArray()
{
    var myArr = new Object();
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
     for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
     {
       if (elems[i].checked)
       {
          myArr[i] = createSubArray(elems[i].getAttribute('name'));
       }
     }
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myArr);
    return myArr;
} 

function createSubArray(name){
    var arr = new Object();
    var elems = document.getElementsByName(name);
    for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i++)
    {
        if (elems[i].checked)
        {
            arr[name] =  elems[i].value;
            arr['price'] =  elems[i].getAttribute('data-price');
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```